# Looking for a verb to use to describe what the rock is doing to you when you're between a rock and a hard place

Tags: single-word-requests

You have two stationary objects eg a rock and a hard place. If you were standing between them and they were both against you, would you say the rock was "pressing" you into the hard place? Would the rock be "holding" you?

Comment: This expression is not really about the rock doing anything to you. It's implying that you have two options. One is a rock, and the other is a hard place. In other words, both options are basically the same (a "hard place" basically being a rock). It's similar to expressions like "six and one half-dozen" … which means that both options are the same, so there's no real choice.

Comment: I was using rock and a hard place as an example of two immovable objects.  Would it be better if I said a brick wall and a bouncer with you sandwiched between the wall and the bouncer? What is the wall doing to you?

Comment: Oh, I see. If it's stopping you from getting away, perhaps something like this: Constraining you, hemming you in, blocking your way, blocking you in, confining or corralling you, trapping you … A few ideas.

Comment: I like "corralling". I'm Australian so we don't use that expression at all. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. I'm Australian, and it seems standard enough to me … although I don't get to use it much, admittedly. I think of it applying more to a group than an individual, tbh, but not sure if that's the case.

Comment: Nah. Once you said "keeping you from getting away" I realized that was a much better way to word it. But I was still chasing a single word. On another note, do we call cattle yards etc corrals?

Comment: Yeah, I guess "trapping" has the sense of "preventing escape". I don't think "corral"  is used as a noun in Aus, but I have heard it as a verb. Most of us would have heard of things like the O.K. Corral, though. :-)

Comment: The word ['kettled'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kettling) might apply to your description.

Comment: In the metaphorical situation, it would that each of the agents is **driving you up** the other.

Comment: You are seeking a literal translation of a metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the rock and the "hard place" represent [*stymies*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/stymie) . The verb is [*to stymie*.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/stymie)

The meaning is that one will have a very hard time going anywhere but where he is.

Being "caught between a rock and a hard place" is a sort of humorous way of saying

> Being caught between two hard places

or

> Being caught between two rocks.

The saying in itself does not express being pressed, but being trapped.

Comment: Interesting.  I hadn't heard "stymie" in maybe 30 years, but it was common when I was a kid.  One would think the term would have become popular in computerese, but I guess not.  (Ngram shows an increase of late, but apparently most of that is due to some character names in fiction, plus the use of "stymie" in golf.)